# if else statement in XElement

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

I am wondering, how can I add a new XElement by using a if/else statement?

For example...

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(this.XMLFile);
document.Element("currentjobs").Add(
     new XElement("job",
            new XElement("date", now.ToShortDateString() + " " + now.ToUniversalTime()),
            new XElement("name", job.name)
            )
     );
```

Now if I wanted to add a new XElement in that XML by using if/else statement from a variable I have in C#.

The if else statement would be like...

```
if(job.status == 2)
{
//add XML...
}
```

How would I go ahead and do this?

Comment: Please be more clear. What kind of if/else?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by if and else ?

Comment: If Else. Such as job.status.

if(job.status == 2)
{
//add XML stuff
}

Answer (score 3):

From [Valid Content of XElement and XDocument Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882.aspx), you can pass `null` to the XElement constructor, and it will not affect the XML tree, so:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(this.XMLFile);
document.Element("currentjobs").Add(
     new XElement("job",
            new XElement("date", now.ToShortDateString() + " " + now.ToUniversalTime()),
            new XElement("name", job.name),
            optionalElement ? new XElement("optional", "value") : null
            )
     );
```